# jaxb, xsd substitution complextype

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have the following xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="screen">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="controls" type="Controls"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Controls">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="control" type="Control" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Control" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Button">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Control">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TextField">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Control">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

How can I generate the following xml document

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<screen ref="10_20_25_vwopstellen">
    <name>VWOpstellen</name>
    <controls>
        <button>
            <name>btnA</name>
            <id>btn_10</id>
            <action>click</action>
        </button>
        <textfield>
            <name>fldA</name>
            <id>fld_20</id>
        </textfield>
    </controls>
</screen>
```

Now it is generating the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<screen ref="scrVWOpstellen">
    <name>VWOpstellen</name>
    <controls>
        <control xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Button">
            <name>btnA</name>
        </control>
        <control xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Button">
            <name>btnB</name>
        </control>
    </controls>
</screen>
```

And when i read my xml document I want a list of contols containing either buttons or textfields

List --> having Button and TextField

I have no idea, i think I should use substitution group but how. I tried something but the xsd is not generating any java code.

thanks

Johan

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an **xs:choice**, and also defining a target namespace, (*http://my.target.namespace* in my example), which can make working with JAXB easier in general.

E.g.:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://my.target.namespace" xmlns:tns="http://my.target.namespace" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="screen">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="button" type="tns:Button" />
                    <xs:element name="textfield" type="tns:TextField" />
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Control" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Button">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:Control">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TextField">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:Control">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Another thought, sometimes the type derivation isn't really worth it.  For something like this you might also just do:

E.g.:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://my.target.namespace" xmlns:tns="http://my.target.namespace" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="screen">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="button" type="tns:Button" />
                    <xs:element name="textfield" type="tns:TextField" />
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Button">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TextField">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```